# (MySQLdb.OperationalError) (1045, "Access denied for user

Tags: python, mysql, docker, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a docker-compose file and a Dockerfile. MySQL is installed properly. I have set MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD. But when trying to access mysql db, getting the error - Access denied.

I am running a docker container with flask app and sql but when I run migrations using the command

```
python manager.py db migrate
```

I faced the below error

sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (MySQLdb.OperationalError) (1045, "Access denied for user 'root'@'172.24.0.3' (using password: YES)")

Here is my docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  backend:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8001:5000"
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: mysql:8.0.34
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: main
      MYSQL_ROOT_USER: root
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    volumes:
      - .dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - "33067:3306"
```

Here is my Flask main.py file

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_cors import CORS
from sqlalchemy import UniqueConstraint


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql://root:root@db/main'
CORS(app)

db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class Product(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=False)
    title = db.Column(db.String(200))
    image = db.Column(db.String(200))


class ProductUser(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer)
    product_id = db.Column(db.Integer)

    UniqueConstraint('user_id', 'product_id', name="user_product_unique")


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'Hello'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True,host='0.0.0.0')
```

and here is manager.py file

```
from main import app, db
from flask_migrate import Migrate, MigrateCommand
from flask_script import Manager

migrate = Migrate(app, db)

manager = Manager(app)
manager.add_command('db', MigrateCommand)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager.run()
```

How may I fix it and continue?

I tried giving it all privileges using the Grant all priviliges to this user in the docker container but nothing seems to work.